# If $f(a)=a$, then $|f'(a)| \leq 1$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be a simply connected proper subset of the complex plane, and let $a\in \Omega$. Let $f: \Omega \rightarrow \Omega$ be an analytic function such that $f(a)=a$. Prove that $|f'(a)| \leq 1$.

By Cauchy's Inequality, we have $|f'(a)| \leq \frac{M}{R}$ for any circle $|z-a|=R$, and $|f(z)|\leq M$.

By definition we have $f(R)=R$. So $|f(z)|\leq R$, i.e. $M=R$.

Thus, we have $|f'(a)|\leq R/R=1$.

Could someone check if my proof is valid here?

Comment: The result is false, since $f(z) = nz$ is analytic on ${\mathbb C}$ for any $n$ with $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(0) = n$. Also, your proof has numerous errors.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Instead of $\Omega$ simply connected, it should be $\Omega$ simply connected and not $\mathbb{C}$. That means $\Omega$ is conformally equivalent to the unit disk. Now reduce to the case $\Omega$ is the unit disk.

Note: It is also enough to assume $\Omega$ bounded.  In this case it will hold for $\mathbb{C}^n$. (Cartan's theorem)

$\bf{Added:}$ Let's see how to prove the fact for $\Omega$ bounded.  Indeed, from Cauchy inequalities, there exists a constant $M$ such that $|g'(a)|\le M$  for all $g$ such that $g(\Omega)\subset \Omega$. Now apply this inequality for $g = f\circ f \circ \cdots f$. We get $(|f'(a)|^n)_n$ bounded, so $|f'(a)|\le 1$.

Comment: better yet, reduce to the case where $\Omega$ is the unit disk and $a=0$.

Comment: Thank you for your help! If a region is simply connected and not the whole complex plane, can it always be conformally equivalent to the unit disk? Also, for the added part, why do we need to have the function $g$ first? Why can't way directly apply the Cauchy's inequality to $f$?

Comment: @Toasted_Brain: Yes to the first question [Riemann theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem); for the second : $g$ will be any function mapping $\Omega$ to itself, so also the compositions $f^{\circ n}$.  I needed another letter...

Comment: So since $|g'(a)|\leq M$, we have that $1 \leq M$. And since $g= f \circ \cdots \circ f$, we have $M=1$. Is this right?